# Why GCC doesn't allow me to create `inline static std::stringstream`?

Tags: c++, gcc, stringstream

I'll go straight to the MCVE:

```
#include <sstream>

struct A
{
    inline static std::stringstream ss;
};
```

GCC 7.2 and 7.1 [refuse to compile](https://godbolt.org/g/RZRpSQ) it with following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream::basic_stringstream()'
     inline static std::stringstream ss;
                                     ^~
In file included from blah:1:0:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/include/c++/7.2.0/sstream:723:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream::basic_stringstream(std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]
       basic_stringstream(basic_stringstream&& __rhs)
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/include/c++/7.2.0/sstream:723:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

You can reproduce that without any flags, as well as with `-std=c++17`.

Clang 5.0 compiles it without any problems.

Other classes (eg `std::string`) can be made `inline static` without problem.

Making it non-inline static removes the error.

Is't a GCC bug or am I missing something?

Comment: What compiler options are you using?  IIRC, `inline` variables are proposed for C++17.  Does the version of GCC you're using require something like `-std=c++17`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle It doesn't work with or without `-std=c++17`, no other flags are needed to reproduce. As I said, inline static variable of other types work fine.

Comment: Possible workaround: `static inline std::stringstream ss{};`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle C++17 is already released

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bug. Reduced to:

```
struct C { explicit C() {} };
struct A {
    inline static C c;
};
```

Something somewhere in GCC's initialization-handling code is incorrectly treating this as a copy-initialization context which ignored the explicit default constructor..