# Why can't std::stringstream be default constructed when it's static inline?

Tags: c++, c++17

The following compiles fine (on g++ 8.3.0-6 and `--std=c++17`) with the `std::stringstream` being a non-static class member:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Foo {
    public:
        std::stringstream ss;
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.ss << "bar\n";
    std::cout << f.ss.str();
}
```

But the following doesn't (same compiler, same options), where the `stringstream` is `static inline`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Foo {
    public:
        static inline std::stringstream ss;
};

int main() {
    Foo::ss << "bar\n";
    std::cout << Foo::ss.str();
}
```

My compiler tells me that `std::stringstream` has no default constructor, which it actually should:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream()’
         static inline std::stringstream ss;
                                         ^~
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: works fine with newer version https://godbolt.org/z/KMKnEEGjc. Did you check if 8.3.0 does implement all C++17 features?

Comment: `static inline` is supported by g++ 8.3. I tried it with `std::string` for example and it works.

Comment: Looks like compiler bug, it works with GCC 9.1

Comment: Seems to be the same question: [Why GCC doesn't allow me to create `inline static std::stringstream`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777900/why-gcc-doesnt-allow-me-to-create-inline-static-stdstringstream), but there's no workaround in answer either. Comment suggests trying to initialize explicitly - `std::stringstream ss{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a compiler bug. It is a little strange that the compiler knows about the constructor overload in one case but not the other, though it might have something to do with the constructor being `explicit`.

This does [compile with 8.3](https://godbolt.org/z/rP4ofcPWM):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Foo {
    public:
        static inline std::stringstream ss{};
};                                      //^^ 

int main() {
    Foo::ss << "bar\n";
    std::cout << Foo::ss.str();
}
```

PS: Also this answer comes to the conclusion that `explicit` is the cause https://stackoverflow.com/a/47782995/4117728.